# NodeJS start mongoDB server

Tags: node.js

I need to start the mongoDB server from my NodeJS application. I managed to do this before but for some reason I forgot how. I though I used a cild process but not sure anymore as I can't get anything to work at the moment.

How would I start the mongoDB server (command mongod) from withing my NodeJS app and execute some other code when the server had been started (guessing using a promise...)?

Comment: First of all, you can not create mongoDB from nodejs file.
At first run' mongod' which start the mongodb process at port 27017. 

" I managed to do this before but for some reason I forgot" 
Please ask a specific question.

Comment: How more specific do you want it? I do not say create mongoDB did I? @AhmadSharif My question is specific as it gets. How to use child processes to start the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **child_process** to run *mongod* from your application, but this may cause the MongoDB server to exit when your app exits. It's generally better to have the DB server running all the time.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Could you please provide some example code? Especially the part where I can insert code that should be run after the server has been started. I keep getting 'exec error: Error: Command failed: mongod' while runnung mongod from the command line works fine.